# In Grails, how do I create and/or update users based on LDAP authentication, then log them in?

Tags: grails, spring-security, spring-ldap

I'm new to Grails, and have jumped into version 2.  I'm developing a project that uses Spring Security 3 - and this is working fine - but I want to use my organisations LDAP server (if / when it is available) to do the following:

- authenticate users
- update the local user data with details from LDAP
- create the user if they don't exist
- update the local users password (in case the LDAP server isn't available)
- log that user in

I may have skipped a lot of fundamental stuff on my way to getting this working, like actually how Grails works - and I'm struggling to understand how to actually interrupt the Spring Security authentication process with an LDAP lookup, then how to get those details back in a way that I can use them to either update an existing user or create a new one...

I found a basic tutorial here: http://jamesjefferies.com/2011/01/06/grails-spring-security-ldap/ which means I can authenticate myself as a user from the LDAP server - although Spring Security still shows me as logged out, but will not let me log in either until I manually log out... so its kind of in a login-limbo.

The magic is doing my head in... at first I was amazed that I could build an entire web-app with a few commands and a few hours customization - but it's coming back to bite me now - as is the lack of useful examples... and the Spring Security LDAP plugin documentation is somewhat lacking (or maybe its my lack of understanding).

So, primarily I would like some help to complete the authentication so that it checks the user database for an existing user and updates them, or creates the user if they don't exist... but I would also love it if someone could give me a brief overview of the authentication process in Grails so I can understand whats actually happening, and where I should intercept things.

Cheers in advance for any help

Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a good example [here](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/LDAP-and-CustomUserDetailsService-td2967149.html) that shows how to implement a custom user details mapper. I used that method on an LDAP login Grails 2.0 app successfully. Basically you have a CustomUserDetailsContextMapper that implements the UserDetailsContextMapper interface which you then use to override the default implementation by registering the bean in conf>spring>resources.groovy. Then inside your CustomUserDetailsContextMapper you check for a user(your domain class) with a matching username and if none exists you creates one using data from the ctx.originalAttrs which contains data from the ldap query results. You must then return a new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User. You can extend this class to add other fields that you want to be able to access directly from the principal object.

Comment: Thanks Dylan, I had read that post and used some of it - but it didn't work for me... I'm going back over the basic documentation now trying to understand why its not but I'm not making a whole lot of progress as yet.  I'll keep trying and post back what I find.

Comment: From that thread the post by David Russell on Nov 04, 2010; 7:17am is the one that really lays out the complete code. I did have to make some adjustments due to our ldap data and the fact that I have to deploy to webSphere which uses an IBM JDK that has some issues, but mostly used the code as it stands.

Comment: Thanks, I'm having a nightmare with it at the moment, so I'll set up a new test application and see if it works in that... but its causing problems with hibernate saying my MyUserDetails has the wrong number of columns... I've gone over it time and again, and everything seems right...

Comment: The user details class should not be getting persisted to the db at all, it should be a regular groovy or java class in a src directory not a domain class. It is instantiated by the mapper and a separate user object is created and persisted only if there is no user with matching username in the db. Hope this helps

Comment: That might just be one of the clues I need... I've been away for a few days but I'll attack it again now... thanks for the hint on where UserDetails should be... I've got it in the Domains...

Comment: I'm getting closer... I figured out how to get Spring Security to post debug-level logging info... its trying to authenticate but failing with this: rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices Interactive login attempt was unsuccessful.  Remember me is turned off, so thats odd... but I'm double-checking the config of LDAP in Config.groovy and experimenting with different configurations.  I'm going to accept you answer now, as it definitely helped get me on track, and I'll post the configuration for others in my predicament once I get it properly working.  Thanks for the help Dylan.

Comment: I have partial success, but I still fail to understand the complexity of making this work.  I can now authenticate by cludging a couple of different things together - but I think I'll rip out all the hideous MyUserDetails stuff and just use the User class from Spring with a few extra fields in it.  Really all I want to be able to do now is hook into the tail end of LDAP authentication and update/create a local user with LDAP details... hopefully I'm not far from figuring that out...

Comment: The only reason to have the myUserDetails is if you want fields like screen name available from the principal without needing to go to the db to retrieve them. If you do that infrequently then ditch it.